# Spark streaming jdbc read the stream as and when data comes - Data source jdbc does not support streamed reading

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using PostGre  as database. I want to capture one table data for each batch and convert it as parquet file and store in to s3. I tried to connect using JDBC options of spark and readStream like below...

```
val jdbcDF = spark.readStream
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://myserver:5432/mydatabase")
    .option("dbtable", "database.schema.table")
    .option("user", "xxxxx")
    .option("password", "xxxxx")
    .load()
```

but it throwed unsupported exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source jdbc does not support streamed reading
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:150)
    at examples.SparkJDBCStreaming$.delayedEndpoint$examples$SparkJDBCStreaming$1(SparkJDBCStreaming.scala:16)
    at examples.SparkJDBCStreaming$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkJDBCStreaming.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
```

Am I in right track ? Really there is no support for database as data source for spark streaming?

AFAIK other way of doing this is write a kafka producer to publish data in to kafka topic and then using spark streaming...

> **Note** : I dont want to use kafka connect for this since I need to do
>   some auxiliary transformations.

Is this the only way to do it ?

What is the right way of doing this ? is there any example for such thing?
Please assist!

Comment: @eliasah do you have any tips for this ?

Comment: Sparks JDBC call is a batch operation. It doesn't repeatedly run a query like Kafka Connect would do

Comment: @cricket_007 I know.... when new data is added it will trigger query. like for example csv folder new csv with same schema added in the folder it will trigger the query. I tried this way. similar thing i am expecting from jdbc

Comment: JDBC natively doesn't know when new data is added or changed... You could use Debezium for this, then transform within Spark from Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 sounds good. but we need docker for Debezium ?

Comment: No. Debezium is just a plugin for Kafka Connect

Answer (score 2):

Spark structured streaming does not have a standard JDBC source, but you can write a custom, but you should understand that your table must have a unique key by which you can track changes.
For example, you can take [my implementation](https://github.com/sutugin/spark-streaming-jdbc-source), do not forget to add the necessary JDBC driver to the dependencies

Comment: Is the library in any repo?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Can you please help me understand, how can I use this solution to a project with pyspark?

Comment: Hi, @HariOm! 
https://github.com/sutugin/spark-streaming-jdbc-source/issues/3#issuecomment-802829838

Comment: @sutugin Thanks for your response. It worked for me, mostly I was struggling with incompatible version dependencies. But as you have mentioned to change default version to upgrade spark and scala version, I tried that but got failed in sbt assemble. So for now I have downgraded my spark version to 2.3.2

Comment: @HariOm, Fixed incompatibility with spark 2.4 and older In the build.sbt file specify only the desired version of spark

Comment: Thanks @sutugin, I have a doubt if this solution  can also work with spark 3.0.1
Because the other custom connectiors we are using dont support data source v2.
Please confirm and Many Thanks for your answers. You helped a lot.

Comment: Hi, @HariOm! I checked on unit tests, with sprak 3.0.1 - it works.

Comment: Thanks much!! I will go with spark 3 then.

Answer (score 0):

This library may help: [Jdbc2S](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/Jdbc2S).

It provides JDBC streaming capabilities and was built on top of Spark JDBC batch source.

Basically, you use it as you would with any other streaming source, the only mandatory configuration is the name of the offset column in the tables you're consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Jdbc2s works for me using pyspark with few changes in JDBCStreamingSourceV1.scala to fit Python keyword convention such as :

```
object JDBCStreamingSourceV1 {
val CONFIG_OFFSET_FIELD = "offsetfield"
val CONFIG_START_OFFSET = "startoffset"
val CONFIG_OFFSET_FIELD_DATE_FORMAT = "offsetfielddateformat"
}
```

Then Finally:

```
def df_readstream(dbtable, offsetfield):
df = spark.readStream.format("jdbc-streaming-v1") \
    .options(url=url,
             driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
             dbtable=dbtable,
             user=user,
             offsetField=offsetfield,
             password=password).load()
return df
```