# Spark structured streaming from JDBC source

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

Can someone let me know if its possible to to Spark structured streaming from a JDBC source? E.g SQL DB or any RDBMS.

I have looked at a few similar questions on SO, e.g

[Spark streaming jdbc read the stream as and when data comes - Data source jdbc does not support streamed reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857171/spark-streaming-jdbc-read-the-stream-as-and-when-data-comes-data-source-jdbc-d)

[jdbc source and spark structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412885/jdbc-source-and-spark-structured-streaming)

However, I would like to know if its officially supported on Apache Spark?

If there is any sample code that would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same requirement (https://stackoverflow.com/q/76703459/5392289)

Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on a project now architecting this using CDC Shareplex from ORACLE and writing to KAFKA and then using Spark Structured Streaming with KAFKA integration and MERGE on delta format on HDFS.

Ie that is the way to do it if not using Debezium. You can use change logs for base tables or materialized views to feed CDC.

So direct JDBC is not possible.

Comment: Hi blue phantom please keep me posted

Comment: Its going fine. Some new things thst alex ott points out.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such **built-in support** in Spark Structured Streaming. The main reason is that most of databases doesn't provided an unified interface for obtaining the changes.

It's possible to get changes from some databases using archive logs, write-ahead logs, etc. But it's database-specific. For many databases the popular choice is [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) that can read such logs and push list of changes into a Kafka, or something similar, from which it could be consumed by Spark.