# Copy of Incremental source table with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, delta-live-tables

A source table in an SQL DB increments (new rows) every second.

I want to run some spark code (maybe with Structured Streaming?) once per day (it is okay if the copy is at most 1-day outdated), to append the new rows since the last time I ran the code. The copy would be a delta table on Databricks.

I'm not sure `spark.readStream` will work since the source table is not delta, rather JDBC (SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structured Streaming doesn't support JDBC source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273386/spark-structured-streaming-from-jdbc-source)

If you have a strictly increasing column in your source table, you can read it in batch mode and store your progress in the `userMetadata` in your target Delta table [link](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/custom-metadata.html#set-user-defined-commit-metadata).

Comment: Thanks - what is batch mode? Is that an option?

Comment: Just a plain `spark.read.format("jdbc")`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform spark.readStream.format("delta").
You have to define a checkpoint, which will store all the metadata related to the streaming pipeline. Let's say you streamed to version 2 on your first run. On the next day when you restart the pipeline, even if your source table is at version 10, the stream will restart from version 3.

Comment: Adding a link to the relevant Databricks page: https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/delta-lake.html

Comment: don't think your proposal is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274909/5392289