# Copy (in delta format) of an append-only incremental table that is in JDBC (SQL)

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-live-tables

My ultimate goal is to have a copy (in delta format) of an append-only incremental table that is in JDBC (SQL).

I have a batch process reading from the incremental append-only JDBC (SQL) table, with `spark.read` (since `.readStream` [is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273386/spark-structured-streaming-from-jdbc-source/71274909#71274909) for JDBC sources). Every day, the most recent day of data is saved as a delta table. Note, this is *not* an append-only delta table - rather it is overwritten every day with the most recent day of data.

What I think I need next is `spark.readStream` out of the delta table, with the `.option("skipChangeCommits", "true")`. The Databricks Documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/python-ref.html#configure-a-streaming-table-to-ignore-changes-in-a-source-streaming-table) outlines exactly this.

I have selected Preview channel in pipeline settings.

The code for the final streaming table in my DLT pipeline is:

```
@table(
    name='streaming table',
)
def create_df():
    return spark.readStream.option("skipChangeCommits", "true").table("daily_batch")
```

However the error here is `NameError: name 'table' is not defined,None,Map(),Map(),List(),List(),Map())`

In case it is a typo in the documentation I have also tried with `dlt.table` and the error is:

`pyspark.errors.exceptions.AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view "daily_batch" cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.`

Comment: Where that table is defined? You didn't put any schema in your name? Is it in same DLT pipeline?

Comment: schema should be inferred from `.table("daily_batch")`, which is the table upstream being read in the code here.

Comment: I wanted to know schema as catalog.schema.table not schema as columns and types, but yeah Alex replied.

Comment: Try using LIVE.daily_batch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to simply use a regular job, not DLT. This simplifies a lot, as there is no need for an intermediate table. It was just:

[JDBC incremental SQL] --Databricks-job--> [delta table write with append only mode].

I saved the watermark as metadata in the delta table with

```
.option("userMetadata", watermark.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))`
```

And read it with each subsequent batch run:

```
dt = delta.tables.DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path)
watermark = dt.history().select(F.col("userMetadata")).first()[0]
```

I used `spark.read.format("sqlserver")` to query from the JDBC server.

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

- instead of `@table` use `@dlt.table` (until you did `from dlt import table`)
- instead of `daily_batch` as table name you need to use fully-qualified name - three (`catalog.schema.table`) or two levels (`schema.table`) (depends on if you use Unity Catalog or not)

But are really sure that it will help you? The doc says:

> skipChangeCommits disregards file changing operations entirely. Data files that are rewritten in the source table due to data changing operation such as UPDATE, MERGE INTO, DELETE, and **OVERWRITE are ignored entirely**. In order to reflect **changes in upstream source tables, you must implement separate logic to propagate these changes**.

Right now you may use a bit different approach (not tested, but should work) - not overwrite the data, but truncate & then append.

Comment: Thanks - taking your tip to delete then append data from the "intermediate" daily delta table. I can load the table as a delta table with `dt=delta.DeltaTable.forPath` and then delete all rows with `dt.delete()`, but how can I append new rows and then still return a table from the function as is required in DLT (with append mode you must specify a save path)

Comment: the first table in DLT must use `spark.read` and not `spark.readStream` since the source data is JDBC; and the next table must use `spark.readStream` in order to keep appending daily?

Comment: I thought that you have JDBC reading as a separate job... Not sure how it could behave if you put everything into DLT